# Is "I will sleep you to bed" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, sentence, transitivity

Like we use "I will walk the dog to the park", is using "I will sleep you to bed" grammatically correct?

Comment: Please have a look at our [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) site, which is better suited to quesions like this.

Comment: For the transitive verb version of *sleep*, the object is basically a type or quantity of sleep.

Comment: It's not a matter of grammar. It is a matter of the meanings of the words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verb *walk* has distinct meanings in *I will walk* and *I will walk the dog*, where in the second expression it means "making the dog walk".

However, we cannot say *I will sleep you to bed*, because there is no meaning of the verb *sleep* that means "making someone sleep".

Answer (score 2):

"Walk" as used in "walk the dog" has more the meaning of "escort." You could certainly say "I will escort you to bed." But not "sleep you..."

Comment: Yes. *Walking the dog* is idiomatic, and there are other ways in which  *walk* can be a transitive verb e.g.*Please would you walk this parcel to the post office*. *Sleep* is sometimes used transitively, especially in advertisements for holiday accommodation e.g. *Delightful cottage with sea views, sleeps eight persons* (That may be essentially British, Americans may not recognise the use). But you, as a person, certainly cannot *sleep someone*. Though, you can sleep with them, or send them to sleep.